# Submit iOS app to the AppStore - ITMS-9000 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

That might be a silly question. But I'm having problems when submiting my app to the AppStore.
Did everything at developer.apple.com until the message "Waiting for upload appears" and then when trying to submit the app through Application Loader I get this message:

[image]

Sorry about printing the image, couldnt copy and paste.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with apple servers. The problem(as the screenshot suggest) was with provisioning profiles that was not set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me too, i suggest waiting some time and then retrying.
Worked for me.

Comment: How long did you have to wait? days? weeks?

Comment: i would say 15 min to couple of hours.

Comment: still nothing, I think it's something else. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: i would suggest to recheck your provisioning profiles in this case, make sure they are signed by distribution one during archiving

Answer (score 1):

If you have not a iPad storyboard, plese edit the "Main storyboard file base name(iPad)" of plist file, Change From iPadStoryboard to iPhoneStoryboard.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are appearing in reverse order.  The original error had to do with you not selecting the right provisioning profile, which caused Xcode to not be able to authenticate the package, which caused the web service operation to not be successful.